# change insert query to update query

Tags: php, mysql, opencart

Im working in OpenCart MVC and im having trouble updating database records. I have a list that shows all the records in the db table. each record has a dropdown with edit as a option. When edit is clicked the form that was filled out is opened with the input filled in with the existing values(all good so far!) when new information is entered the user should be able to hit the save button and have that update the db. currently the save button query is a insert query. So I suppose its not writing because it already has records in it. Id also rather not add a new button(ie update) Id like to be able to use the existing save button. How do I change the model to reflect this? Do I have a insert and an update query and some kind of check? Do I do this on the controller? Im a little confused on how to do this.

MODEL:

```
public function addCampaign($data) {

        $this->db->query("INSERT INTO " . DB_PREFIX . "campaigns SET campaign_name = '" . $this->db->escape($data['campaign_name']) . "', campaign_giving_goal = '" . (float)$data['campaign_giving_goal']
        . "', code = '" . $this->db->escape($data['code']) . "', campaign_active = '" . $this->db->escape($data['campaign_active']) . "', campaign_giving_count_goal = '" . (float)$data['campaign_giving_count_goal'] . "', campaign_owner = '" . $this->db->escape($data['campaign_owner']). "', date_beginning = '" . $this->db->escape($data['date_beginning']). "', date_ending = '" . $this->db->escape($data['date_ending']). "'");

        $this->cache->delete('campaign');

        return $campaign_id;
    }
```

CONTROL:

```
public function add() {
        $this->load->language('campaigns/campaign');

        $this->document->setTitle($this->language->get('heading_title'));

        $this->load->model('campaigns/campaign');

        if (($this->request->server['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') ) {


            $this->model_campaigns_campaign->addCampaign($this->request->post);
            $this->model_campaigns_campaign->addComponent($this->request->post);
            $this->session->data['success'] = $this->language->get('text_success');
            $url = '';          

            if (isset($this->request->get['order'])) {
                $url .= '&order=' . $this->request->get['order'];
            }

            if (isset($this->request->get['page'])) {
                $url .= '&page=' . $this->request->get['page'];
            }

            $this->response->redirect($this->url->link('campaigns/campaign', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'] . $url, true));
        }

        $this->getForm();

    }
```

VIEW:

```
<div class="cancel-save">
                  <button type="submit" form="form-campaign" data-toggle="tooltip" title="<?php echo $button_save; ?>" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="submitForms()"><i class="fa fa-save"></i></button>

                  <a href="<?php echo $cancel; ?>" data-toggle="tooltip" title="<?php echo $button_cancel; ?>" class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-reply"></i></a>
                </div>
```

Comment: If possible, use *prepared statements with placeholder values*. This could be a simple wrapper around PDO so you should have access to all of those features.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one.
On controller modify like this.

```
public function add() {
    $this->load->language('campaigns/campaign');

    $this->document->setTitle($this->language->get('heading_title'));

    $this->load->model('campaigns/campaign');

    if (($this->request->server['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') ) {
        if (!isset($this->request->get['campaign_id'])) {
            $this->model_campaigns_campaign->addCampaign($this->request->post);
            $this->model_campaigns_campaign->addComponent($this->request->post);
        } else {
            $this->model_campaigns_campaign->updateCampaign($this->request->get['campaign_id'], $this->request->post);
            $this->model_campaigns_campaign->updateComponent($this->request->get['campaign_id'], $this->request->post);
        }
        $this->session->data['success'] = $this->language->get('text_success');
        $url = '';          

        if (isset($this->request->get['order'])) {
            $url .= '&order=' . $this->request->get['order'];
        }

        if (isset($this->request->get['page'])) {
            $url .= '&page=' . $this->request->get['page'];
        }

        $this->response->redirect($this->url->link('campaigns/campaign', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'] . $url, true));
    }

    $this->getForm();

}
```

Then add this code on model

```
public function updateCampaign($campaign_id, $data) {

    $this->db->query("UPDATE " . DB_PREFIX . "campaigns SET campaign_name = '" . $this->db->escape($data['campaign_name']) . "', campaign_giving_goal = '" . (float)$data['campaign_giving_goal']
    . "', code = '" . $this->db->escape($data['code']) . "', campaign_active = '" . $this->db->escape($data['campaign_active']) . "', campaign_giving_count_goal = '" . (float)$data['campaign_giving_count_goal'] . "', campaign_owner = '" . $this->db->escape($data['campaign_owner']). "', date_beginning = '" . $this->db->escape($data['date_beginning']). "', date_ending = '" . $this->db->escape($data['date_ending']). "' WHERE campaign_id = '" . (int)$campaign_id . "'");

    $this->cache->delete('campaign');
}
```

I can not provide the updateComponen model because you don't write it. Maybe you can use updateCampaign code as referense to write it.